# How import own js file into vite?

Tags: javascript, laravel, frontend, vite

I use Laravel with Vite and I want to add file with Vanillia JS code. Before I used mix and I have never use Vite before. I tryed add this code into file vite.config.js like below example:

```
laravel({
    input: [
        'resources/sass/app.scss',
        'resources/js/app.js',
        'resources/js/test.js', //this is my code
    ],
    refresh: true,
}),
```

but it doesn't work. I need to add one library and code with config that. Could you help me?

Comment: Ah, it's that time of the year again! Laravel released a new version and now I have to relearn how to do JS.

Answer (score 7):

**This is applicable for your own created js files and node modules library js files**

You need to both declare it in `vite.config.js` and initial HTML file (`app.blade.php / welcome.blade.php`)

In vite.config.js

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/js/test.js', //your custom js
                'node_modules/flowbite/dist/flowbite.js', //node modules js
                'node_modules/flowbite/dist/datepicker.js'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

In HTML.blade.php

```
<head>
     @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js',         
     'resources/js/test.js',node_modules/flowbite/dist/flowbite.js' 
     ,'node_modules/flowbite/dist/datepicker.js'])

</head>
```

*P.S: I am using Flowbite plugin as an example here*

Comment: I have noticed that, when doing that, in html it reflects as: ```<link rel="modulepreload" href="http://pathurl.test/build/assets/test-7d2614e6.js">``` and though I have searched, I have yet to find and sort of assurance that this works the same as using <script> tags...

Comment: Isn't it possible to do import "./test"; in app.js? So it's being merged in app.js. I notice console.log is being removed after build.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `@vite('resources/js/test.js')` directive:
https://legacy.laravel-vite.dev/guide/usage.html#vite

```html
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
        <title>Laravel</title>
        @client
        @vite('main')
        @vite('resources/js/some-script.js')
        <!-- 
        In development:
            <script type="module" src="http://localhost:3000/@vite/client"></script>
            <script type="module" src="http://localhost:3000/resources/scripts/main.ts"></script>
            <script type="module" src="http://localhost:3000/resources/js/some-script.js"></script>
        In production:
            <script type="module" src="http://laravel.local/build/assets/main.66e83946.js"></script>
            <script type="module" src="http://laravel.local/build/assets/some-script.6d3515d2.js"></script>
        -->
    </head>
```

Comment: For me it gives this error: Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/js/searchinput.js.

Answer (score -1):

IN LARAVEL 10

main.blade.php:

```
<head>
    @vite(["resources/js/app.js"])
</head>
```

IN TERMINAL:

```
npm install

npm run dev
```

OPEN OTHER TERMNAL AT THE SAME TIME

```
php artisan serve
```

GO TO SERVE PAGE SOMETHIG LIKE
http://127.0.0.1:8000

*thanks Fguzman*

Comment: Is this an answert to the OP question?!